# GCC debugging option -dH

Tags: gcc

From this link: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

> -dH Produce a core dump whenever an error occurs.

So, I compiled a program with a syntax error and the core file was generated. How can that core file be used now? GDB can't be invoked since any executable has not been generated, yet.

```
[11:11:12 Wed Apr 27]
~/junk1  $ls
core  hell.c

[11:11:15 Wed Apr 27]
~/junk1  $gcc -g hell.c -dH
hell.c: In function ‘main’:
hell.c:4: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
gcc: Internal error: Aborted (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <http://bugs.opensuse.org/> for instructions.

[11:11:36 Wed Apr 27]
~/junk1  $ls
core  hell.c

[11:12:09 Wed Apr 27]
~/junk1  $gdb cc1 core
GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (6.8.91.20090930-2.4)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-suse-linux".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
***cc1: No such file or directory.***
Missing separate debuginfo for the main executable file
Try: zypper install -C "debuginfo(build-id)=41f1efcceccfa5fa0b3476021c731c489547f86e"
Core was generated by `/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.4/cc1 -quiet hell.c -quiet -dumpbase hell.c'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007fb1b01654e5 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

The GDB says: cc1: No such file or directory, in the above output.
How I am supposed to use that core file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that switch is to help debug **gcc**, not your program. The [page you link to](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) starts like this:

> 3.9 Options for Debugging Your Program **or GCC**
>   GCC has various special options that are used for debugging either your program **or GCC**:

Emphasis mine.

The `cc1` program is an internal part of GCC, it is probably somewhere under `/usr/lib/` or `/usr/libexec/`.

Comment: May be you are right, is there any option by which GDB can find the syntax errors?

Comment: @Anisha: I think you'd need to know the GCC internals to figure out what the syntax error was.

Answer (score 1):

`gdb -c corefile` should work.  I haven't had to use the `-dH` option, so not sure how useful it is in helping with debugging.

Comment: It didn't work: I wrote: gdb -c core
 and GDB said: `(gdb) r
Starting program:
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
(gdb)`

Comment: @Anisha Kaul I don't understand.  Why would you want to try `run` inside gdb, given that you know there was no executable generated thanks to the error you introduced?  examining the core file should work.  Examining the frames, and such.

Comment: THe GCC said (as shown in the first post): `gcc: Internal error: Aborted (program cc1)` so I thought cc1 might be some kind of executable :eek: Core files are not human readable, so how should I examine them? Secondly you told me to run: `gdb -c core`?

Comment: `gdb -c core` is one way to ask gdb to open up a core file.  It has commands built in for examining the core file.  Perhaps you could try debugging the cc1 binary, but that is going to take more work and knowledge of gcc's internals

Comment: `gdb -c core` is simply refusing to work, in this case at least.